# What Methode is called on repainting a class extending JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I am repainting my Obstacle extends JPanel from another Class as well as from the Obstacle constructor. Inside the paintComponent(Graphics g) my Sys.out is never printed -> Method is never called. 
I've implemented all of this 100 times and cannot find any difference between this and other working codes :c

```
    private Rectangle hitbox;
    private int x,y, width, height;
    public static final int BIG = 0, LARGE = 1, BIRD_LOW = 2, BIRD_MID = 3, BIRD_HIGH = 4;

    public Obstacle(int x, int y, int type) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        [...]

        this.repaint();
    }

    public void updateMovement() {
        this.x -= 10;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(hitbox);
        System.out.println("Repainted");
    }
}
```

Comment: repainting in your constructor makes no sense, as your Obstacle has not yet been added to the GUI. Therefore, there's no graphics object, and therefore paintComponent isn't being called

Comment: And instead of using final constants you would be best served by using an `enum`.